# Thread and MultiThread structure issue

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpoolexecutor

I'm struggling with how to summarize my problem since there may be questions that need to be asked before proposing a solution. I'll do my best to answer any queries.

I have a series of functions: `A(), B(), C(), D().` These are called within a try block like this:

```
void CalculateX() {
    try {
        A();
        B();
        C();
        D();
    } catch (...) {
        // handle exceptions
    } finally {
        E();
    }
}
```

The functions inside this try block are processed on a different hardware thread. I'm invoking the CalculateX function from React Native. To avoid locking the UI or causing delays, CalculateX needs to be executed on a separate thread. Each time a button is clicked in the React interface, the CalculateX function is called. Here's a solution I've come up with (the code isn't "clean," but my priority is resolving the issue):

```
class TaskExecutor {
    static ExecutorService singleTaskExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    
    static CountDownLatch latch;
    
    @ReactMethod
    static void displaySale(String msg_1, String msg_2, Context reactContext, QuarkCallback callback, FiscalPrinterExecuter fiscalPrinterExecuter, LogModule log) throws InterruptedException {
        singleTaskExecutor.submit(() -> {
            try {
                if(latch!=null || latch.getCount()>0)
                     latch.await();
                latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
                A();
                B();
                C();
                // ... other calls
            } catch (FiscalException | InterruptedException e) {
                // log.addRecordToLogJ("Fiscal Error or Interruption");
            } finally {
                E();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

As expected, when the latch's count reaches 1 and latch.wait is called, it stops the single thread that is performing the display action, thus preventing any further processing on this thread.

Now, my question:
The functions A, B, C, D... E are being processed internally on a different thread (although A, B, C, D, and E are processed within the same thread, they're part of a library function which, in turn, manages a new thread on its side). Since they are processed on a different thread, calling A, B, C, D functions doesn't wait for their completion (the process might take 3 seconds, but it proceeds immediately without waiting). How can I manage this within a thread queue?

Note: The E function deals with hardware, akin to an `End()` operation, which shuts down the hardware.
Note 2: If the A function is called twice in succession (without the E function being processed in between, like -> A B C D A), the hardware crashes.

I expect this thread structure works as I expected.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! 
In your case I would recommend using "Futures" to Wait for Completion. Your CountDownLatch prevents re-entrance of the displaySale method. This is a good strategy to prevent A from being called again before E has been processed, but you need to reset the latch after E has been called, not before waiting for it.

Comment: If A, B, etc. don’t give you some way to know when they’re complete, there is nothing you can do, unless they produce some result you can monitor.  I’m not clear on why the CountDownLatch is needed, since you’re already executing these tasks on a single threaded executor, which guarantees they will never run concurrently.  Also, `if(latch!=null || latch.getCount()>0)` does not do what you think it does;  if for some reason latch is null, that line will throw a NullPointerException.  You probably meant to use `&&` instead of `||`.